# Set threshold for realfield input widget

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all:

I'd like to set threshold for the input value in the realfield widget. The code below will create a realfield widget, and the threshold of input value is between 0 to 0.05.

If you input 0.06 inside the widget, and then click somewhere out of the GUI, it will warn you it's not a correct value, and reset the value to last value.

But if you input 0.05, it will not warn you. And then if you input any other value, it will say "Wrong config file".

I double checked the logic and doesn't find any wrong code. Could anyone help me debug? Thanks a lot.

Regards

Chen ZX

```
Number get_tag_as_number(TagGroup tg, String tag_path, String tag_type, Number low_limit, Number high_limit)
{
    Number tag_value, tag_is_valid
    if (tag_type == "Boolean") tag_is_valid = tg.TagGroupGetTagAsBoolean(tag_path, tag_value)
    if (tag_type == "Number") tag_is_valid = tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(tag_path, tag_value)
    if (!tag_is_valid)
    {
        Result("ERROR: Can not get tag value of " + tag_path + "." + "\n")
        ShowAlert("Can not get tag value of " + tag_path + ".", 0)
        Exit(0)
    }

    if (tag_value < low_limit || tag_value > high_limit)
    {
        Result("ERROR: Wrong config file, " + tag_path + "." + "\n")
        ShowAlert("Wrong config file, " + tag_path + ".", 0)
        Exit(0)
    }
    return tag_value
}

Class testUI : UIFrame
{
    TagGroup ui_config_tg
    Void tg_init(Object self)
    {
        ui_config_tg = NewTagGroup()
        ui_config_tg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat("display_font:init_value", 0.015)
    }
    TagGroup create_realfield_widget(Object self)
    {
        Number low_limit = 0
        Number high_limit = 0.05
        Number init_value = get_tag_as_number(ui_config_tg, "display_font:init_value", "Number", low_limit, high_limit)
        TagGroup realfield_widget
        realfield_widget = DLGCreateRealField(init_value, 16, 3, "action")
        realfield_widget.DLGIdentifier("#realfield_widget")

        return realfield_widget
    }
    Void action(Object self, TagGroup item_tag)
    {
        Number low_limit = 0
        Number high_limit = 0.05
        Number curr_value = item_tag.DLGGetValue()
        Number init_value
        init_value = get_tag_as_number(ui_config_tg, "display_font:init_value", "Number", low_limit, high_limit)



        if (curr_value < low_limit || curr_value > high_limit)
        {
            OKDialog("Font size must between " + low_limit + " to " + high_limit)
            self.LookUpElement("#realfield_widget").DLGValue(init_value)
            item_tag.DLGValue(init_value)
            Exit(0)
        }
        ui_config_tg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat("display_font:init_value", curr_value)
        Result( curr_value)
    }
    
    TagGroup create_dialog(Object self)
    {
        self.tg_init()
        TagGroup realfield_widget = self.create_realfield_widget()
                
        TagGroup tabs = DLGCreateTabList()
        tabs.DLGAddElement(realfield_widget)
        TagGroup dialog = DLGCreateDialog("test")
        dialog.DLGAddElement(tabs)
        return dialog
    }
    
    
    testUI(Object self)
    {

        self.init(self.create_dialog())
        self.Display("test")

    }
}

Alloc(testUI)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is fine, but you are running into rounding issues which are particularly hard to spot on scripting languages with automatic number & string conversions.

- DM-Script `number`is internally handled as *double* (in GMS 3 at least)
- When you write the value to tags as *float* you loose precision.

It is saver to stick with `...asNumber` to avoid these issues. You need to be type specific only in cases where it matters, like streaming to a binary stream.

See the following example

```c
number tag_value = 0.05
number low_limit = 0
number high_limit = 0.05

clearresults()
Result("\n Limits are (double):")
result("\n: low limit:  "+low_limit)
result("\n: high limit: "+high_limit)

Result("\n Tag value is (double):")
result("\n tag value:  "+Format(tag_value,"%20.12f"))
Result("\n (tag_value - low_limit) : "+(tag_value - low_limit))
Result("\n (tag_value - high_limit): "+(tag_value - high_limit))

taggroup tg = newTagGroup()

tg.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber("Test",tag_value)
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber("Test",tag_value)

Result("\n ~~~~~ Now with Tag read & write as NUMBER (internally this is DOUBLE)")
result("\n tag value:  "+Format(tag_value,"%20.12f"))
Result("\n (tag_value - low_limit) : "+(tag_value - low_limit))
Result("\n (tag_value - high_limit): "+(tag_value - high_limit))

tg.TagGroupSetTagAsDouble("Test",tag_value)
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsDouble("Test",tag_value)

Result("\n ~~~~~ Now with Tag read & write as DOUBLE")
result("\n tag value:  "+Format(tag_value,"%20.12f"))
Result("\n (tag_value - low_limit) : "+(tag_value - low_limit))
Result("\n (tag_value - high_limit): "+(tag_value - high_limit))

tg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat("Test",tag_value)
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsFloat("Test",tag_value)

Result("\n ~~~~~ Now with Tag read & write as FLOAT")
result("\n tag value:  "+Format(tag_value,"%20.12f"))
Result("\n (tag_value - low_limit) : "+(tag_value - low_limit))
Result("\n (tag_value - high_limit): "+(tag_value - high_limit))
```

Alternatively, you can fix your script by not checking against "0" exactly, but a against a small epsilon value that accounts for the precision problem:

```c
[...]
    number eps = 1e-9
    if ((tag_value - low_limit)< eps || (tag_value - high_limit) > eps)
    {
        Result("ERROR: Wrong config file, " + tag_path + "." + "\n")
        ShowAlert("Wrong config file, " + tag_path + ".", 0)
        Exit(0)
    }
```